# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value with toInt()

Tags: swift, option-type

I am getting the error that is in the title, when I run my code. The main problem occurs in the code below. I don't really understand what is going on. I started (and completed) this project to make a bingo tracker in swift during the beta, but apparently the syntax changed or something. I would prefer an easy fix with an explanation of why my solution does not work any more. I provided all of my code and would appreciate if no one reused it, but I can not really stop you. Thank for the help.

```
if ((newCardB1?.text.toInt()) != nil) // this is not nil
    {
        println(newCardB1?.text); // this prints out "Optional("1") when i run it but i only want the 1
    }
    else
    {
        println("error" );
    }
    let B1: Int = "\(newCardB1?.text)".toInt()!; //this is where the problem starts
    let B2: Int = "\(newCardB2?.text)".toInt()!;
```

PS: I have limited programming experience with swift, but a lot with Java. Any tips on the switching back and forth would also be appreciated and feel free to state any other problems or bad coding techniques so that I am able to fix them.

Comment: you can start deleting all semicolons and ommiting types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change all the statements of the type **let B1: Int = "(newCardB1?.text)".toInt()!;** to this template: **let B1: Int = (newCardB1?.text)!.toInt()!**. The reason is: newCardB1?.text is already a string. If you interpolate it using "()", I am not sure where it ends up. Also note the ! in (newCardB1?.text)!. The code will not compile without it.

With regard to your style, it is clear you are from Java. Semicolons are rarely needed in Swift. Other than that the style is fine. Perhaps a little verbose.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have fixed it.